# Does the getSpeed() in Location object account for Altitude change

Tags: android, gps, location

I was wondering for one of the apps I'm writing does the [Location.getSpeed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getSpeed()) account for Altitude change? i.e. if I am going down a slope does it return a speed as if I'm going straight or does it actual do the calculation based on the triangle formed due to the downward slope?

Comment: I do not believe it takes slope into account, reason for this assumption is that Android doesn't have a native means of detecting altitude. Unless GPS coordinate have an elevation I am unaware of, it would be difficult for Android to use slope as a variable. However, if you take the math into consideration, you would need a pretty extensive slope for it to make a large difference in speed calculations (in other words, it should still be "fairly" accurate without slope)

Comment: Thanks. Yes that makes sense. The use case I was considering was Snowboarding. Since the altitudes can change pretty dramatically, I was wondering if the gps based altitude even detects those changes so fast. Do you know if any app does or can possibly give accurate speed for such cases so that I can compare?

Answer (score 0):

The `Location` class does NOT consider altitude when giving you the speed.

The source for `getSpeed` is

```
public float getSpeed() {
    return mSpeed;
}
```

And `mSpeed` assignment is `mSpeed = (Parcel)in.readFloat();`. Ultimately, if I'm not mistaken, it looks like the `Parcel` comes from [`ILocationManager.aidl`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/location/java/android/location/ILocationManager.aidl) which is private so I don't know, but I would guess it pretends you're not on a slope when it decides what the speed is.

And a lot less fun, but the docs say about `getSpeed()`:

> Get the speed if it is available, in meters/second over ground

which sounds like it does not consider altitude changes.

If you really want to know, you could somehow test it or you could [file a bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=Developer%20Documentation) regarding the `getSpeed()` documentation.

Comment: so u dont know if it considers altitude.

Comment: That's what I said, but all available signs seem to point to it not calculating altitude changes. But, if you file a bug you can find out whenever the docs for the function get updated.